# Why is a += x slower than a = a+x?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm working on optimizing a python program for which I have speed issues.
I was playing about on another document with various things that appeared on my program which could influence total speed of execution.

I found that:

```
a = 0
for x in range(10000000):
    a += x
return a
```

is slightly slower than:

```
a = 0
for x in range(10000000):
    a = a + x
return a
```

The first script takes between 1.5 and 1.55 seconds to execute, while the second takes regulary about 1,36-1.37 seconds (using cProfile).

Any idea why this could be? Thank's :)

Comment: What does `dis.dis()` say ?? I feel `a += x` should be fast slightly

Comment: In-place version is slightly slower because `int` does not define its own in-place addition, namely, slot `nb_inplace_add` for `int` is `0`. See http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.1/file/8e5812b35480/Objects/longobject.c#l4918

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to do proper timings. It avoids common pitfalls, uses the most precise timer implementation for your platform and tries to minimise the influence of OS scheduling by repeating the tested code *many* times.

Using a profiler on the other hand adds a lot of overhead to support instrumenting the full call stack; `timeit` measures the complete execution time, not individual calls in the stack.

Using `timeit` shows the two versions are too close to call (default is 1 million iterations):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a += x', 'a = x = 1')
0.047940969467163086
>>> timeit.timeit('a = a + x', 'a = x = 1')
0.04770612716674805
```

Both operations are *one* bytecode:

```
>>> def f(): a += x
... 
>>> def g(): a = a + x
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Could you please explain in short, why `timeit` is better?

Comment: That was clarifying, thank you. Probably my timing just got wrong, I will use 'timeit' the next time.

Answer (score 0):

`a += x` is basically not an increment operation. You are assigning the variable `a + x` to `a` again. Which is pretty much the same as assigning the the value of the variable with `a = a + x`.

So as Pieters mentionned, there is no reason to have such gap in timeit.

+++++ EDIT to DSM

integers in Python are immutable: you increment `a` if you increment `b` if you defined

`a = 5`

and

`b = 5`

so that to 'increment' b, you have to 'reassign' it to `b`, that is what i meant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying `a += x` is not an increment operation.  It's not the same as `a = a + x`, they use different special methods, `__add__` vs `__iadd__`.  In principle they could do totally different things.

Comment: Ah, it makes more sense now that you've clarified you're referring specifically to the integer case, and not to `a += x` operations in general.